# How to output numpy array from the animation script node

Tags: scripting, animation-nodes

is there a way to output a numpy array from script node in ?
Or do i have to make my own output class types in the socket folder of this addon ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Generic` type to output ndarrays.

[image]